# Testing error flows with Spring Cloud Streams

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I've started a small microservice using Spring Cloud Streams.

I just have two stream binding as follows:

```
 cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        channelone:
          destination: org.queue.app.EventsOne
          contentType: application/json
          group: app
        channeltwo:
          destination: org.queue.app.EventsTwo
          contentType: application/json
          group: app
```

I have component tests developed with Serenity and I inject the channels to where I want to send test messages:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(Channels.EVENTS_ONE_CHANNEL)
SubscribableChannel eventsOneChannel

@Autowired
@Qualifier(Channels.EVENTS_TWO_CHANNEL) 
SubscribableChannel eventsTwoChannel
```

where:

```
Channels.EVENTS_ONE_CHANNEL and EVENTS_TWO_CHANNEL
```

Are just defined as string constants:

```
@UtilityClass
public class Channels {
    public static final String EVENTS_ONE_CHANNEL= "channelone";
    public static final String EVENTS_TWO_CHANNEL= "channeltwo";
}
```

The component tests module import the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm sending the messages like:

```
eventsOneChannel.send(someMessage)
```

The happy flows work fine. However I want to test the error flows when the listener fails to process the message.

This is an example of a listener:

```
@StreamListener(Channels.EVENTS_ONE_CHANNEL)
@SendTo(Channels.DTO_GENERATED)
public BonusDTO receive(Message<String> message) {
    try {
        log.info("Received Event event with payload [{}]", message.getPayload());
        return toDto(message.getPayload());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Error converting Event to DTO", ex);
        throw new EventHandlingException(ex);
    }
}
```

When an exception is thrown from the try/catch, the error is handled by a service activator:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "org.queue.app.EventsOne.app.errors")
public void handle(ErrorMessage errorMessage) {
   log.info("Error");
}
```

When running the app, without the spring-cloud-stream-test, if an error-handling the message occurs, then the previous service activation get fired and the error is handled.

However, the same does not happen during the tests. Using spring-cloud-stream-test, when an exception is thrown from the listener, the service activated from errors channel does not get called.

I want to test the error flows also.

Is this a limitation of spring-cloud-stream-test? Any configuration, trick or tip, to have the error messages sent to error channels when using spring-cloud-stream-test?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joao Pereira I think there is a bigger issue(s) at play here, so I'll try to lay it out with hopes of providing some clarity

1. Ability to have error handler method annotated with ServiceActivator is a contract provided by the framework, which means its testing is our responsibility. Further more the mechanism you are using is not even from Spring Cloud Stream but rather from Spring Integration. But regardless, I am questioning whether applications should be testing it at all given that you can not influence it in any way at the application level since it's not your functionality.
   Again, this is my opinion and I would be very interested to see what you think.
2. With Spring Cloud Stream 3.0.0.RC1 (and subsequent release) we are effectively deprecating `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` in favor of a [new test binder](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-stream.adoc#testing) that Gary has mentioned. The reasons for it are documented in the link i just provided, but please feel free to follow up with questions. And although its usage is fairly well documented, here is [one of the test cases](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/tck/ContentTypeTckTests.java) where we're using it ourselves for your reference. And although the examples in the ref doc are showing function-based message handlers it works the same way with annotation-based message handlers (which is what you are using).
3. Speaking of annotation-based programming model please see the following blogs we just published (an look for more as they are in works) where we're laying out the case why we're moving away from annotation-based programming model and I think you should begin considering changing you code as well. After all the changes would pretty much amount to removing all annotations and slightly changing the signature of your message handler methods to be represented as function beans

   - https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/14/spring-cloud-stream-demystified-and-simplified
   - https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/17/spring-cloud-stream-functional-and-reactive
   - https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/25/spring-cloud-stream-and-spring-integration

The reason why I am saying all this are many, but your code above and your concerns expressed reminded me once again why we are moving away from such programming model.

I'll stop here as I believe here is a lot to digest, but please feel free to follow up with more pointed question given wha I just stated.

Comment: Thanks for the time. About point 1) I asked myself the same question. Should I treat the error handling as a separate application by itself?
The flow is managed by spring integration. Happy flows work fine, with the correct services being activated, so I thought I could do it the same way for error flows...
I will look for the spring integration test library, I'll find answers there.
About point 3) That's great news and I'll dig more the links. After reading your second post, I also realized that there are better ways to implement a lot of use cases in a more reactive way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

spring-cloud-stream-test enables a very basic test binder; it doesn't have all the features of a real binder.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I suspected that

Comment: IIRC, there's a new test binder in the works; not sure of its status.